# Returning value from setter

Tags: c#, struct, accessor

I have an immutable struct and would like to keep it immutable, but also allow schematics like `var p2 = p1.v = 3`. I thought that the following might work, but it appears not:

```
public struct Number {
    readonly int n;

    public int N {
        get{ return n; }
        set{ return new Number(value); }
    }

    public Number(int newN) {
        n = newN;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get `var p2 = p1.v = 3` or `var p2 = (p1.v = 3)` to work?

Comment: What is it you want to do exactly?

Comment: this is wrong. Why would you like to return a value from a setter?

Comment: Not only returning a value from a setter is wrong but also the return type does not match the data type specified in the property

Comment: what is v in p1.v? do you mean N? yea, I agree with @Leo, you cant do a return in a property setter. Just doesn't work that way.

Comment: It would be VERY helpful in explaining why you would WANT to do something like this.

Comment: Returning a value from a setter isn't necessarily wrong. The result of validations can be returned as an enum, boolean or integer (instead of an exception). Or you can create a fluent API for easy method chaining.

Comment: I want to do it in order to access more compact syntax. For example, in scala, you can do this, and I'd like to replicate it here.

Comment: @user60561: can you clarify what exactly you want to do? What is that syntax supposed to reach?

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel `public Number setN(int newN){ return new Number(int newN);}` With multiple numbers, this can be significantly shorter.

Comment: @user60561: The question is what do you actually want to achieve? While syntactically it is possible to write something like `var num2 = num1.setN(1).setN(2).setN(3).setN(4);` you would loose the Number objects with the values 2 and 3, as they will not be kept somewhere and soon be garbage-collected after calling this line of code...

Comment: @elgonzo From what I understand, structs do not require garbage collection under most circumstances and so the overhead will be minimal because allocations will be on the stack and removed when the value leaves the scope.

Comment: But what's the point of creating an object if you're never going to keep it around in the first place?

Comment: @user60561: You are right about structs and GC, but the effect of loosing (or not keeping) the two inner numbers would remain the same. It is still unclear what you are shooting for...

Comment: I think I've found another alternative, `Number this(int newN = n){return new Number(newN);}` This syntax us equally simple, `num1[n = 2]` and avoids the fluid interface's lengthiness.

Comment: @user60561: Wait, you used an array indexer (with square brackets)? While this might work (haven't thought about that), you will confuse anyone reading your code. It's kind of code only you will understand ;)

Comment: @elgonzo Yes, my goal was to keep the syntax as clean as possible. Is there something wrong with doing so style-wise? I'm very new to this particular language.

Comment: @It is not clean (short, perhaps). Square brackets are commonly associated with (array) indexers. Abusing (array) indexer syntax to save a few characters in your source code will lead to misunderstandings and confusion - it is bad practice, so to speak. Strictly speaking, the square bracket indexers are not limited to be implemented just for arrays and collections (although that is what most people know about), but can also be implemented for index-based access to any dataset you implement. Is it that what you try to achieve?

Comment: That sounds reasonable, I'll avoid indexers for non-indexes, thanks.

Comment: An question to the community: does the setter always return "void"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no syntax like this that will work. Setters are, well, *setters*, not a way to *get* something.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you want to do something that no one will be able to read. If you structure is immutable what one should expect as result of `p1.v = 3`? Obviously `p1` should not change, no one expect setter to return value... the only reasonable behavior would be to see an exception "This object is immutable", but than lack of setter would be much better indication of the property being read only....

Possibly you trying to implement something like [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)  which is much more common:

```
 var newValue = oldValue.WithOneProperty(5).WithOtherProperty(3);

 class Number 
 {
   int oneProperty;
   int otherProperty;
   Number WithOneProperty(int v) { return new Number(v, this.otherProperty); }     
   Number WithOtherProperty(int v) { return new Number(this.oneProperty, v); }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only return values from getters.

Comment: Can? No. Should? Probably.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, in the context of property accessors in C#, setters **cannot** return values. (Not to confuse with SetXXX/GetXXX methods, though, where calling a method a setter is just a convention...)

Comment: Definitely, the way this was worded made it sound like he was referring to common setter methods.

Comment: So was i completely wrong when i said "you CAN only return values from getters"?

Comment: @OjonugwaOchalifu, no, you were not completely wrong, just ambiguous. Before the advent of the property get/set accessors in C#, the terms "setter" and "getter" where just used for ordinary methods such as GetWidth/SetWidth or alike (and are still used in other languages). Since those are just methods, one could implement a setter (setter method!) with a return type. For property setter (a set accessor!) this is syntactically not possible - the compiler just gives you an error message if you would try to return a value.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a valid use for this with one-time-tokens or keys. I used some of the code here to generate this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private static string m_oneTimeKey = "this key hasn't been initialised yet";

    private string oneTimeKeyGet()
    {
        // Return the last key
        string returnValue = MyController.m_oneTimeKey;

        // Generate a new random key so the one we return can't be reused
        var m_oneTimeKey = GetRandomString();
        return returnValue;
    }

    private string oneTimeKeySet()
    {
        // Generate a new random key
        var newValue = GetRandomString();
        m_oneTimeKey = newValue;
        return newValue;
    }

    private string GetRandomString()
    {
        var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        var random = new Random();
        var returnValue = new string(
            Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 8)
                      .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                      .ToArray());
        return returnValue;
    }
```

And then I use it with:

```
 var myURL = "/Index?id=" + ID + "&key=" + oneTimeKeySet();
```

And within the ActionResult I can verify if this is the one time call with:

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid id, string key)
    {
        if (key == oneTimeKeyGet() {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

I've actually gone a step further and I also have a static key that is passed between functions that is also checked for in the if in the ActionResult.